# Hook menu in the page--front.tpl with a passed var

Tags: routes

Given the url, for example:

website/all

I wish the hook_menu, to load the existing frontpage, currently using a page--front.tpl.

passing the "all" arg to the page so I know I need to load all records.

One will presume I need to start off with hook_menu......with a page callback, but how will the function load the page?  IS there a function I can call?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an existing page with the URL alias of `all`? If so, then you could copy over the page template from page--front to page--all.tpl.php (https://www.drupal.org/node/104316). If you don't have a page with the URL alias of /all you would need to define a hook_menu item for ['all'] or create a View/alias for that page.